# linq query with count

Tags: linq, count, group-by

I would like to create a simple linq query, but I don't really know, how it should be. I have searched the net, but found nothing, what I can use or I don't know yet, that I could use it.

So, basically, I have a table with this fields: reference, vat_code, amount, vat_amount, supplier.

Now, I would like to query the records, where reference<>'' and the reference is more than once in the table. But I need all the occupians.

F.e. from

```
1;VF;100;27;345
2;VF;200;54;123
2;VF;-200;-54;123
2;VF;200;54;123
3;VF;300;81;888
```

to

```
2;VF;200;54;123
2;VF;-200,-54;123
2;VF;200;54;123
```

How would be look the linq query to this?

Thanks.

Comment: Is the order of the records important?

Comment: What do you mean by *table*? Is it database table, or DataTable object? What if there another row with reference 3 *between* rows with reference 2? What is expected result in that case? Should rows with reference 3 go together in result?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If rows with same reference should go together in results, then you should filter out rows with reference equal to empty string, then group all rows by reference and select only those groups which have more than one row.

C# sample with DataTable:

```
var result = dt.AsEnumerable()
               .Where(r => r.Field<string>("reference") != "")
               .GroupBy(r => r.Field<string>("reference"))
               .Where(g => g.Count() > 1)
               .SelectMany(g => g); // flatten group to sequence of rows
```